# Attribute as a verb

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Attribute as a verb what does it mean? Give an example. As a noun it is similar to skill / characteristic

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look in the dictionaries? What is it said there?

Comment: Yes i looked there: to say that a situation or event caused by something/ someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's the definition from [Oxford's Learners dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attribute_1I):

1. **attribute something to something** - *to say or believe that something is the result of a particular thing*:

   - *She attributes her success to hard work and a little luck.*

   This means that "*hard work and a little luck were the result of her success.*"
2. *To say or believe that somebody is responsible for something, especially for saying, writing or painting something*:

   - **attribute something** - *The committee refused to attribute blame without further information.*

   This means that "*the committee refused to ascribe blame*".

   - **attribute something to somebody** - *This play is usually attributed to Shakespear.*

   This means that "**Shakespear is believed to be responsible for writing this play**"

Another explanation by [Oxford's living dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20191219225044/Lexico.com/definition/attribute):

1. **to attribute something to** - regard something as being caused by something.

   - "*his resignation was attributed to stress*" - stress was the cause of his resignation.
2. **to attribute something to someone** - to ascribe a work or remark to (a particular author, artist, or speaker)

   - "*the building was attributed to Inigo Jones*" - the building is ascribed to be the work of Inigo Jones.

Comment: Oxford dictionary explain better than long man dictionary which I had. Thanks, sometimes even if i look in the dictionary I did not get the full meaning and where to put the word in a sentence.

Comment: @Ameryr In the future I advise you to search definitions in Oxford, Merriam-webster, Cambridge, and Collins. I'm not saying that Longman dictionary is worse but I prefer those I've listed.